# Saving strings into list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a function which returns strings. What I would like to do is get these strings and save it into a list. How can I do this?

```
for i in objects:
    string = getstring(i)
    x = 0
    list[x] = string
    x = x+1
```

Comment: You are assigning `string` to `list[0]` every time you loop in `for`. Declare list before `for` loop: `list = list()` and do `list.append(string)` without any x's. But better use list comprehensions as @thefourtheye [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24523762/3240679)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use a list comprehension in this case,

```
my_list = [getstring(obj) for obj in objects]
```

Instead of creating a list and storing string in it, we are creating a list of strings, based on the objects in `objects`. You can do the same with `map` function as well

```
my_list = map(getstring, objects)
```

This takes each and every item in `objects` and applies `getstring` function to them. All the results are gathered in a list. If you are using Python 3.x, then you might want to do

```
my_list = list(map(getstring, objects))
```

Since using `map` is not preferred, whenever possible go with List Comprehension. Quoting from the [BDFL's blog](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2009/04/origins-of-pythons-functional-features.html),

> Curiously, the `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` functions that originally motivated the introduction of `lambda` and other functional features have to a large extent been superseded by list comprehensions and generator expressions.

Comment: This is indeed more "pythonic" way to solve the case.

Comment: In my case, the function that returns the string actually returns several values, one of which is a string. How can the first code you gave be modified?

Comment: @MSK If you know the index of the item you want to get, then you can simply do `my_list = [getstring(obj)[1] for obj in objects]`, assuming `1` is the index of the items you want to get.

Comment: Yes. This works perfectly. But I've run into some issue now, when I print the string, it prints as it is. but when I use list comprehension or even L.append and print the list, the string appears as the following. E.x. list = [u'string1',u'string2',u'string3']

Comment: @MSK what is your problem with that? You can convert that to a string like this, `[str(getstring(obj)[1]) for obj in objects]`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to remove the u'  ' in the strings

Answer (score 4):

You should first declare the list:

```
L = []
```

then, in the `for` loop, you can append items to it:

```
for i in objects:
    string = getstring(i)
    L.append(string)
```